# StartsWith match on per-word basis. Space to be treated as AND operator

Tags: javascript, regex

On a huge list of strings, I need to facilitate filtering. The user would type in a few characters which will be used for performing `startsWith` match on a per-word basis. Any `white-space` character should be treated as an `AND` operator.

Let's say, if the user types in `Ad Ade A`, it should match strings having words starting with `Ad`, `Ade`, `A` (order not important). Each word typed by the user should have atleast one `startsWith` match in the string.

e.g 1.

```
Af Ele Ada
```

would match

```
"Adam likes African Elephants"
"Test Adam Africa Elephant Africa Adam"
```

but not match

```
Adam likes Australian Elephants (since no word starts with Af)
```

e.g. 2

```
Ad Ade A
```

would match

```
"JunkCharacters Adenine Test1 Adam Test2 Abcd Test3"
```

but not match

```
"Adam Adam Adam" (since no word is starting with Ade)
"Adenine" (since Ade matches Adenine and there are no matches for Ad and A).
```

Is it possible to construct a regular expression for this matching? If possible, a single regular expression would be preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using lookaheads you can do this in single regex like this:

```
^(?=.*\b(Ade\w*)\b)(?=.*\b(?!\1)(Ad\w*)\b)(?=.*\b(?!\1|\2)(A\w*)\b).*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lW1aG9/3)

**Code to build regex:**

function lookaheads(n){
   var str="";
   for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
      str += "(?!.*\" + i + ")";
   return str;
}

```
var s = 'Ade Ad A'

c=0;
var re = new RegExp('^' + s.split(/\s+/g).map(function (m) {
   return "(?=.*\\b" + lookaheads(c++) + "(" + m + "\\w*)\\b)";
}).join(''), 'g');

//=> /^(?=.*\b(Ade\w*)\b)(?=.*\b(?!.*\1)(Ad\w*)\b)(?=.*\b(?!.*\1)(?!.*\2)(A\w*)\b)/g
```

**Now test it:**

```
re.test("Adenine Adam Ball A")
true

re.test("Adenine")
false

re.test('JunkCharacters Adenine Test1 Adam Test2 Abcd Test3')
true
```

Comment: Tried this with `var s = 'Ad Ade A';` and test string `Adenine Ae A`. This returns true which is incorrect since there is no match for `Ad` (`Adenine` is already matched by more specific `Ade`)

Comment: As per my Q `Any white-space character should be treated as an AND operator.` Also think of it this way, in my usecase, I want to help users to filter the huge list based on their inputs. Would a string having just `Adenine` makes sense if the user has typed `Ade Ae`? And I'm sorry, I'm unable to come up with meaningful example instead of `Ade Ae`, that could've helped more.

Comment: [Does this regex give you desired match result?](https://regex101.com/r/lW1aG9/3)

Comment: Thanks, this is very close to what I want. This doesn't match string like `Adam Adenine Adam`, but I can improve on this. Please update the answer and I will accept.

Comment: Also I think user supplied words should be matched against repeated words so matching `Adam` twice shouldn't be considered  a match.

Answer (score 1):

Have a regular expression for each token and `AND` the results together like:

```
string.match(/\bAd/) && string.match(/\bAde/) && string.match(/\bA/)
```

Additionally, depending on the search characteristics you could consider building an index of words. With an index *startsWith* can be a very fast operation. O(log n) with an index vs O(n) without.

---

Elaboration on the index:

You can build a reverse index. Let's say you have the documents:

```
1 "Adam likes African Elephants"
2 "Test Adam Africa Elephant Africa Adam"
3 "Adam likes Australian Elephants"
4 "JunkCharacters Adenine Test1 Adam Test2 Abcd Test3"
```

Your reverse index would like like:

```
Adam       1 2 3 4
African    1
Elephant   2
Elephants  1 3
likes      1 3
etc..
```

In that index, because of the startsWith characteristic, you can do a binary search for your tokens, that makes the search a really fast O(log n).

Building the index takes time though. So if your documents change a lot, or if you have relatively few documents, it might not be worthwhile.

Comment: 1) Thanks for the quick answer. Is it possible to have a single regex, instead of have a regex for each word the user types? 2) Could you elaborate on the index option, this like a good idea and would love to understand more.

Comment: I don't think so since a regular expression can only match a word once. `A`, `Ad` and `Ade` have the characteristic that they all match the word `Adelle` (for instance). Also, the order of the tokens is not important, that's fixable in a regular expression but it would significantly increase it's complexity.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

http://jsbin.com/temaso/edit?js,console

```
var sentances = [
    "Adam likes African Elephants",
    "Test Adam Africa Elephant Africa Adam",
    "JunkCharacters Adenine Test1 Adam Test2 Abcd Test3",
    "Adam Adam Adam",
    "Adenine"
];

var goodMatch = function(searchstring,sentance) {

  // ensure ALL search words match at least ONE sentance word
  return searchstring.split(/\s+/).every(function(searchWord) {
    return sentance.split(/\s+/).some(function(targetWord) {

        // ensure search word has a length, and create regex based on it
        return searchWord.length && new RegExp('^'+searchWord).test(targetWord);
    });
  });
};

var search = function(searchstring) {
    return sentances.filter(function(sentance){
        return goodMatch(searchstring,sentance);
    });
};
```

```js
console.log = function(input) {
  // hijack console.log() for Stack Overflow code sandbox
  var output = JSON.stringify(input);
  var newli = document.querySelector('#debug li[hidden]').cloneNode();
  newli.removeAttribute('hidden');
  newli.innerHTML = output;
  document.querySelector('#debug').appendChild(newli);
};

var sentances = [
 "Adam likes African Elephants",
 "Test Adam Africa Elephant Africa Adam",
 "JunkCharacters Adenine Test1 Adam Test2 Abcd Test3",
   "Adam Adam Adam",
   "Adenine"
];

var goodMatch = function(searchstring,sentance) {
 
  // ensure ALL search words match at least ONE sentance word
  return searchstring.split(/\s+/).every(function(searchWord) {
    return sentance.split(/\s+/).some(function(targetWord) {
  
      // ensure search word has a length, and create regex based on it
      return searchWord.length && new RegExp('^'+searchWord).test(targetWord);
    });
  });
};
                                      
var search = function(searchstring) {
    return sentances.filter(function(sentance){
  return goodMatch(searchstring,sentance);
    });
};

console.log( search("Af Ele Ada") );
console.log( search("Ad Ade A") );
```

```html
<ol id="debug">
  <li hidden><pre><code></code></pre></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm already doing this and was looking out for a magical regex expression :) . I couldn't convince myself if such a regex can't be arrived at, so posted a question here.